# How to remove specific ending of words in a file on Java?

Tags: java, regex, file

I would like to remove all endings of words in a file e.g. remove all -ed (worked, loved, ruined, Photoshopped, manipulated) to (work, lov, ruin, Photoshopp, manipulat)

I have no idea how to do it, I was looking for regex syntax, but what I got is removing only one symbol at the end

```
 aLine = aLine.replaceAll("[\\<ed>]\\b", "");
```

Input was:

> Sitting at a typewriter at home worked photoshopped

I got:

> Sitting at a typewriter at hom worke photoshoppe

What is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: `aLine = aLine.replaceAll("ed\\b", "")`

Comment: your regex matches: "any of `<`, `e`, `d`, `>` followed by a wordboundary" `[]` defines a set of characters where one of them needs to match. Defining a sequence of characters that need to match is done by simply writing the sequence out, i.e. `ed` like in above comment

Comment: are you trying to find the root words, that is stemming?

Comment: I would like to make something like stemming but it is not necessary to do it like should be :) it is enough to remove some ending and beggining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the following regex:

```
(?<=\w)ed\b
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/z9GNct/1)

**Explanations:**

- `(?<=\w)` or `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` impose that there is a word character at the left of `ed`, or a letter (constraint that it is part of word)
- `\b` imposes that the character is followed by a word boundary character

Then you adapt it to your code:

```
String input="I have worked a lot and ruined my health but I have loved my job even if "
        + "I habe been manipulated and ruined by this Photoshopped picture. "
        + "Ed and Eddy are happy today even if they have partied the whole night. ";

String output=input.replaceAll("(?<=\\w)ed\\b", "");
System.out.println(output);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
I have work a lot and ruin my health but I have lov my job even if I habe been manipulat and ruin by this Photoshopp picture. Ed and Eddy are happy today even if they have parti the whole night.
```

Regex quick start sheet: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

**Generalization**:

```
(?<=\w)[a-zA-Z]{2}\b
```

You can use this regex if you want to remove last 2 letters of all words (longer than 2 characters in your input string)

**IMPROVEMENT:**

It is also possible to remove the lookbehind and to use simply the following regex: `\Bed\b` for `ed`-ending words and `\B[a-zA-Z]{2}\b` to remove the last 2 letters of all words (longer than 2 characters in your input string)

Thank you [**revo**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) for this improvement!

Comment: You could remove lookbehind and use a boundary: `\Bed\b`

Comment: @revo: yeah that's even better ;-) since some languages do not like lookbehind/lookahead thanks!!! ;-) I have edited my post